# Check for role assignment including groups

Tags: 2010, roles

I've a site which uses some custom roledefinitions for assigning rights to users. I have implemented a method which checks if a certain user is assigned to a specific role, this method is as follows:

```
public bool IsUserInRole(SPUser user, SPWeb web, string roleName)
{
  SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(user);
  SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions[roleName];

  return roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Contains(roleDefinition);
}
```

Now this works, but it doesn't take groups into account. For instance, if I place the user in a group which has contribute rights on a site, this function still returns false when I check for contribute rights.

I couldn't find the API call to perform the check the way SharePoint does it. Who knows if this call exists and if not: what would be a good way to mimic it? I could ofcourse get all the groups the user is enrolled in, get the assigned roles for those groups and check if the specified role exists in those collections; but that sounds a bit ugly and less performant.

To add some more info: SPUser.Groups only get's the SharePoint defined groups, so when you want to use this in combination with AD groups, even iterating the Groups property won't do.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for a code snippet like this in forever. Great work, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out:

```
public static bool IsUserInRole(SPUser user, SPWeb web, string roleName)
        {
            SPPermissionInfo info = web.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo(user.LoginName);
            SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions[roleName];

            foreach (SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment in info.RoleAssignments)
            {
                if (roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Contains(roleDefinition))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Should this work? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I already tested it.You get any error?

Comment: Yeah, when I'm logged in as an FBA user and I try to do this call, I get an error page instantly. Doesn't matter if I run it elevated or not, access is being denied. It does work when I'm logged in as a site admin, but then it doesn't seem to return the rights inherited by the domain group.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was using the SPContext.Current.Web object for checking, and since that is initialized as the current user, there were insufficient permissions to enumerate the rights. Getting the corrent site/web inside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges fixed this. Works great, thanks!

Comment: I updated the code to handle the case when a user is assigned to many groups. Please note.